# How to start a new clause on a new line in Cypher Query while typing in Neo4j Browser, Currently "Enter" or "Return" key executes the Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I want to follow the Cypher Style Guide while typing in the query in Neo4j Browser, "Enter" or "Return" key executes the Query while I want to start a new clause on a new line to write remaining part of the query.

If "Enter" or "Return" key executes the Query, what is the Keyboard Key or Combination of Keys which will allow me to start a new clause on a new line?

Please guide.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally Enter key runs the queries but most of the time you’d need to work with queries spanning multi-lines.

To accomplish that you can simply use **`Shift+Enter`** to start a new line and **switch to multi-line mode.**

Once you switch to multi-line mode, the line numbers will appear and Enter will no longer run your query but will start a new line.

To run queries in multi-line mode you can use **`Ctrl+Enter`** key combination.

Comment: Is there any document where I can read this type of feature list of Neo4j browser or Desktop?

Comment: You can find some tips here:  https://volkanpaksoy.com/archive/2015/02/16/neo4j-browser-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: see `:help keys` as documented in https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser`